# posting Php variable without href tag to other file

Tags: php, forms, variables

this is my first file code, where the php code is inside an html form and sending data by post method:

```
    <form name="quiz" action=quizaction.php  method="POST"> 
    <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `type` IN 
     ('".implode("','",$fin_element)."')";

     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     $index = 0;
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.1'/>
          <code>".$row["answer1"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.2'/>
          <code>".$row["answer2"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.3'/>
          <code>".$row["answer3"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.4'/>
          <code>".$row["answer4"]."</code>". "<br>";    
   $index++;

   echo $index; 
}
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
          }
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Done" >
  <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Clear all fields of this form">
```

i want to use the  $index variable in other file named quizaction.php file ,how do i ??

Comment: use session or send this value using `<form action="">` as you alreay using

Comment: can you share some code for reference... for the <form action="">

Comment: use session or post the value by assigning it to a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSION

```
  <form name="quiz" action=quizaction.php  method="POST"> 
        <?php
         session_start();//session starts here
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `type` IN 
         ('".implode("','",$fin_element)."')";

     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     $index = 0;
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br>";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.1'/>
          <code>".$row["answer1"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.2'/>
          <code>".$row["answer2"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.3'/>
          <code>".$row["answer3"]."</code>". "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.4'/>
          <code>".$row["answer4"]."</code>". "<br>";    
   $index++;

   echo $index; 
}
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
          }
// set session value and use $_SESSION['index'] at quizaction.php to find session value
if($index> 0){
 $_SESSION['index'] = $index;
}
?>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Done" >
  <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Clear all fields of this form">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take hidden text-box in your form. then you can get that value in  quizaction.php file.

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
";
      echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "
";

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.1'/>
      <code>".$row["answer1"]."</code>". "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.2'/>
      <code>".$row["answer2"]."</code>". "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.3'/>
      <code>".$row["answer3"]."</code>". "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='question".$index."' value='answer1.4'/>
      <code>".$row["answer4"]."</code>". "<br>"; 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='indexid' value='".$index."'/>
```

$index++;

echo $index; 
}

Comment: You can get "indexid" input text in your next page.